# How do I associate a domain, with an existing WordPress blog?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

I've purchased a domain for my daughter, who wants it to use her blog on Wordpress.com. What isn't clear to us is how to associate the domain I've purchased from the registrar, to her Wordpress.com blog. How do we do that?

Comment: WordPress.com questions are [off topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Please check with [their official support](https://wordpress.com/support/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is reasonably well documented on https://wordpress.com/support/domains/map-existing-domain/